# Quantization problem

Tags: communication, digital-communications, sampling

Following is the problem:

A sinusoidal signal $$A_c\cos(2πf_ct + φ)$$, where φ is uniformly distributed over $$[−π, π]$$, is quantized by a 1-bit quantizer. Assume that the signal utilizes all the representation levels of the quantizer. What will be the signal-to-quantization noise ratio?

I have done some basic problems on quantization but I am not sure how to proceed when a probability distribution is given.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this is a good question for the [Signal Processing stack exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

without loss of generality, it doesn't matter what \$\varphi\$ is and it can be assumed \$ A_c \ge 0 \$.

since this is a 1-bit quantizer, the sole quantizing threshold is at 0.  then the error will depend on the ratio of the output level of the quantizer and \$ A_c \$.  let the 1-bit quantizer be defined as:

$$ \hat{x}(t) \triangleq \frac{\Delta}{2}\operatorname{sgn}\{ x(t) \}  $$

where \$ x(t) = A_c \sin(2 \pi f_c t + \varphi) \$ and the stepsize \$ \Delta > 0 \$.

and the quantization error is

$$ \epsilon_x(t) \triangleq \hat{x}(t) - x(t) $$

if the output level of the 1-bit quantizer is \$\pm 1\$ (which means \$\Delta=2\$) and \$ A_c \$ is a million, you can expect an awful lotta quantization error.  but this 1-bit quantizer will behave exactly the same as if \$ A_c = 2 \$ in which the quantization error would be far less.  somehow, a 1-bit quantizer has an inherent gain factor in it and that has to be modeled from some knowledge of the nature of the amplitude of \$x(t)\$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I still do not see how to solve the problem at hand. How do I go about finding the noise here? Sorry if I miss something obvious here. Thanks again!

Comment: well, when \$x(t)>0\$, then \$\hat{x}(t)=+\frac{\Delta}{2}\$ and when \$x(t)<0\$, then \$\hat{x}(t)=-\frac{\Delta}{2}\$.  see if you can come up with an expression for \$\epsilon_x(t)\$.  then square it and find the average of the square.

Comment: To find the average, I need to integrate it over something but what is the integration variable here? How do I factor in the distribution of $\varphi$ here? Can you please help me set up the integral for this?

Comment: turns out that it doesn't matter what \$ \varphi \$ is.  you can set it to any number you want.  the averaging of \$ |\epsilon_x(t)|^2 \$ is over time and you can do that averaging over one period.

Comment: Ok, let \$ \varphi \$ be zero. Then the integral is: \$ \frac{1}{T}\int_0^{T} (\hat{x}(t)-A_c\sin(2\pi f_c t))^2dt \$. Solving this is not too hard but I fail to see why the distribution doesn't matter here. :/

Comment: you haven't expanded out the integral yet.  assuming \$ T = \frac{1}{f_c} \$ you need to make an expression for \$ \hat{x}(t) \$.  then you will find that the integral will need to be split into two.  one for \$ \int_0^{T/2} \$ and another for  \$ \int_{T/2}^T \$.

Comment: Yes, I know very well that I need to split the integral into two but my question is about the distribution of \$ \varphi \$.

Comment: sorry, we're just going round in circles and i am too lazy to repeat myself.